# How to wrap an existing c++ library built by gcc4 for Python compiled by gcc5+?

Tags: python, c++, gcc, wrapper

Is there any approach unaffected by different GCC version to wrap an existing c++ library for Python?

Currently, We choose **SIP** to wrap [a shared c++ library of supermap GIS](https://gitee.com/GIScript/GIScript2016/tree/master/Bin64_Linux_gcc4_9). There is a couple of headers and so files built by **4.9.2**. It will fail when **python3** compiled by **gcc 5** or above to call the wrapped library. The error message is `undefined symbol XXXXXX....`(see the subsequent information). If **we can't change gcc version and source code of library**, how to call the library in python without any pain?

Here is tesing code :

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://gitee.com/seifer_08ms/docker-giscript --depth=1
cd docker-giscript
# It works with default gcc 4.8 and python 3.6.2 
docker build -t seifer08ms/gispark-notebook  . 
# It works with default gcc 5.4.0 and python 3.6.2
docker build -t seifer08ms/gispark-notebook --build-arg GCC_VERSION=5  .
```

The error messages is 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/GIScript/GISCore.so: undefined symbol:  _ZN7VariantC1EhsixfdRK9TimeStamp6BinaryRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEESB_`

After testing many differrent version of gcc and python, I found the critical is the version of gcc to built python3 and SIP modules. It works with from gcc 4.6 to gcc 4.9 , failed with gcc5+.The version of python3 is not the key.

Comment: which library, which symbol, which python

Comment: Does it fail when loaded or when built? The actual name of the missing symbol could help (even if one might make an educated guess...).

Comment: I have edited my question with supplementary information. Please give me a help again.

Comment: @ead, It fail when imported from python. The undefined symbol is  _ZN7VariantC1EhsixfdRK9TimeStamp6BinaryRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEESB_

Comment: c++filt demangles missing symbol as "Variant::Variant(unsigned char, short, int, long long, float, double, TimeStamp const&, Binary, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&)", a non-default constructor.

Comment: There was an abi change between gcc4 and gcc5 https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html. Building your extension with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 will probably fix it.

Comment: @ead, it works now. Thanks!